# Restricting user from repeating color in slots with data attributes

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a drag and drop with angular and i'm using data-attributes, but I've been struggling recently. I want to restrict the user from having repeated colors in the 3 boxes I have, there should be someway to stop the user to have the same color repeated in the slots.

my html:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-bottom sticktobot">
    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="peg red col-xs-1" x-lvl-draggable="true" data-color="red"></div>
            <div class="peg green col-xs-1" x-lvl-draggable="true" data-color="green"></div>
            <div class="peg blue col-xs-1" x-lvl-draggable="true" data-color="blue"></div>
            <div class="peg black col-xs-1" x-lvl-draggable="true" data-color="black"></div>
            <div class="peg yellow col-xs-1" x-lvl-draggable="true" data-color="yellow"></div>  
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="r in [1]" class="centerpls col-xs-4 chosenbox" >
            <span class="slot" ng-repeat="c in [1, 2, 3]" x-lvl-draggable='true' x-lvl-drop-target="true" x-on-drop="dropped(dragEl, dropEl)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my js:

```
<script>
    angular
        .module('ddApp', ['lvl.directives.dragdrop']) // register the directive with your app module
        .controller('ddController', ['$scope' , function($scope){ // function referenced by the drop target
            $scope.dropped = function(dragEl, dropEl) {
                //this is application logic, for the demo we just want to color the grid squares
                //the directive provides a native dom object, wrap with jqlite
                var drop = angular.element(dropEl);
                var drag = angular.element(dragEl);

                //clear the previously applied color, if it exists
                var bgClass = drop.attr('data-color');

                if (bgClass) {
                    drop.removeClass(bgClass);
                }

                bgClass = drag.attr("data-color");
                drop.addClass(bgClass);
                drop.attr('data-color', bgClass);

                //if element has been dragged from the grid, clear dragged color
                if (drag.attr("x-lvl-drop-target")) {
                    drag.removeClass(bgClass);
                }


            }
        }]);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found how to

```
var bgClass2 = drag.attr("data-color");
if(jQuery(".slot").hasClass(bgClass2))
    {

    }else{
            bgClass = drag.attr("data-color");
            drop.addClass(bgClass);
            drop.attr('data-color', bgClass);
    }
```